# Error: "Could not find rake", yet Rake is installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, rvm

Why am I receiving this Rake error:

```bsh
$ rake --version
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rake (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:18:in `<main>'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

given that the following is the case:

```bsh
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)
rvm (1.11.3.3)
$ which rake
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake
```

Specifically: is this error message stemming from a **bug**, or from a **configuration problem** (and if the latter, then which steps might remedy it)?

---

**Update:** additional terminal output as requested:

```bsh
$ which gem
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem
$ whereis rake
/usr/bin/rake
$ echo $PATH # I've edited the output as one item per line for easier reading
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/bin:
/opt/local/bin:
/opt/local/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/texbin:
/usr/X11/bin:
/usr/local/git/bin:
/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion:
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/bin:
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/bin
$ type rvm | head -n1
rvm is a function
$ rvm info

ruby-1.9.3-p194:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin spksmb.lan 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.14.3 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "9 hours 36 minutes 53 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p194"
    date:         "2012-04-20"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin10.8.0"
    patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    ruby:         "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion:/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    IRBRC:        "/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Running `rvm get stable` has not helped.

Comment: Running `gem update` followed by `rvm gemset use global` (necessary even though the "global" gemset is the only one I have) followed by `gem cleanup` did not help, either.

Comment: Can you also give a `which gem`, just so we're comparing apples to apples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the problem was occurring because of the presence, in the directory from which I was executing the commands shown in the question, of a file called `Gemfile` with the following contents:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec
```

Deleting or renaming that file yields the following (yay!):

```
$ rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2.2
```

By contrast, keeping the Gemfile, but deleting or renaming the `myproject.gemspec` file from the directory yields this:

```
$ rake --version
/Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:48:in `gemspec': There are no gemspecs at /Volumes/Data/spikes/myproject. (Bundler::InvalidOption)
    from /Volumes/Data/spikes/myproject/Gemfile:4:in `evaluate'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:18:in `build'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:123:in `load'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:41:in `candidate?'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:60:in `setup'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Volumes/Data/sampablokuper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

The fact that the behaviour of `rake --version` is so strongly influenced by the presence/absence/contents of these files does strike me as a bug, and I'll be filing a bug report accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The 'whereis' binary checks a set of system default paths set by the user.cs_path variable (see `sysctl -a | grep user.cs_path`) and NOT the actual $PATH variable. So the 'rake' location reported will *always* be whatever happens to be in that set of paths and *not* the actual one in use, unless that truly does happen to be the *only* rake installed on the system and thus not showing up in $PATH.

Please run

```
which rake
```

to see which rake is actually being used. If it reports /usr/bin/rake and not some path such as /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake then definitely something is wrong.

Please include

```
rvm info
```

output and make sure that

```
type rvm | head -n1
```

reports "rvm is a function". If it is reporting anything other than that, your install is messed up, in which case you should remove your rvm install using `rvm implode`, logging out completely, and then doing a complete reinstall of RVM. Yes, the logout step is important.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the difference between `which` and `whereis`. The output of `which rake` was included in my initial question, and is still present in the question. The output of `whereis rake`, I added in response to @alterpub's reply, although I couldn't personally see how it would be helpful. Will provide the other info you asked for shortly.

Comment: I've now added output of `rvm info` and `type rvm | head -n1` to the question, as requested. Thanks again for looking into this.