# Scheduling rake task with cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, rake

I'm trying to set daily cron job to update my site stats, but it looks like it doesn't work.

Cron entry (for deployer user):

```
0 0 * * * cd /var/www/my_site/current && rake RAILS_ENV=production stats:update
```

I'm running ubuntu server, with rbenv.
Any idea  what's wrong?

Comment: Checkout the `whenever` gem, which makes scheduling jobs much simpler for Rails apps: https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: I faced the same problem. Solved!

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18096502/1524350

Answer (score 0):

Many times $PATH is defined differently when cron runs compared to when you are working in your own shell. Do "whereis rake" to find the full path to rake and then replace "rake" with its full path. (I am assuming that the "cd" command is working, so I am focusing on whether "rake" is found / running properly.)

Has cron sent you any emails with error messages after you added your command to your crontab?

You might want to run "crontab -l" under the proper user account to make sure that your cron command is actually registered within the crontab, especially if you aren't receiving any emails.

The presence of a Gemfile can also affect the ability to properly run rake. See, for example, [Error: "Could not find rake", yet Rake is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151416/error-could-not-find-rake-yet-rake-is-installed)